# Iteration with a cursor via stored procedure or a Join/Partition SQL Server / Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a 4-4-5 Fiscal Year calendar that starts from a Sunday (Jan 3, 2016). 
I have created a view with a column Fiscal Year, Fiscal Week (From 1 - 52), and Min (Date), Max(Date). This creates the Start and End Date for each of the Fiscal Week in the Fiscal Year.

Given that I have a particular order that may span a number of invoices with various dates. I would like to create get the total number of weeks for the invoices based on the Invoice date.

Originally I was thinking of creating a stored procedure that would accept an orderid and then loop through each week and if there was an invoice date based on invoice it would increased the counter. It would go through all 52 weeks.

However, I am wondering if there is another way I can do this can I perhaps create a function that would look through the invoice table and do a join with the view and partition by the Weeks or something? Help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without knowing what your tables look like, but my guess is that all you need to do is get the `datediff(day, myFiscalYearStartDate, MAX(orderDate)) / 7 - datediff(day, myFiscalYearStartDate, MIN(orderDate)) / 7`?

Comment: @ZLK that won't work. Because I may have weeks that may not have invoices. Its not consecutively billed.

Comment: So if an invoice for a week doesn't exist, then no work was done in that week? If so, you'd probably just need to do a datediff against every invoice date then count the (distinct?) results... e.g. I'm assuming if there's invoices for weeks 1, 4 and 5 that counts as 3 weeks?

Comment: Yes...exactly. But how would I do that....considering I have a table called orderInvoices with the columns, Invoice Date, Orderid, InvoiceNo. ...and a view of the Fiscal Calendar with the columns Fiscal Year, Fiscal Week (1-52) and Start Date of the Week for that Fiscal Week and End Date of the Week of that Fiscal week. What would that datediff look like?

Comment: Well, there's a few different ways you could do it. But from what you described (I didn't realise you had a fiscal year table like that) I'd guess something like the following would work: `SELECT orderID, COUNT(DISTINCT fiscalWeek) FROM (SELECT o.orderID, f.fiscalWeek FROM orders o CROSS APPLY (SELECT fiscalWeek FROM fiscalTable WHERE o.invoiceDate BETWEEN startDate AND endDate) f) t GROUP BY orderID` but it's hard to know whether this would definitely work without sample data. NOTE: this assumes your invoice date is a `DATE` and not a `DATETIME`. date times get a bit tricky with `BETWEEN`

Comment: Thanks ZLK that worked great. I created it as a function based on the orderid.